# uriString after taking a photo in some devices

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, camera

When I take a photo in my OnePlus 3 with Android 8.0 the app crashes, but in my Genymotion with Android 6.0 it works perfectly.

Camera intent.

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePicture, TAKE_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

How I'm setting up onActivityResult()

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{       
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == TAKE_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);

        String path = getRealPathFromURI(tempUri);
        try {
            Img img = crearImg(path);
            if (user.isOnline()) {
                Img.uploadImage(NoteActivity.this, img);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}

    }

}
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, can you show your logcat? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, without specific crash log we can't answer your question precisely. I'd say based on the version numbers and simulated vs. real device, it probably has something to do with data storage. (Maybe external vs. internal write permissions?) Also, the camera intent is notoriously a problem across multiple devices as each manufacturer has its own custom camera app.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding a check for result code would prevent the crash but not necessarily fix the problem?

```
if (requestCode == TAKE_IMAGE_REQUEST && && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   //your code here
} else {
   //log error here to figure out the problem
}
```

Also, I'm not sure why you are calling `super` in `onActivityResult`. You should only need that in your `onPause()`, `onResume()`, `onStart()`, etc methods. `onActivityResult()` is called before these methods, but as you declare the variables in the input `int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data`, why the super call to the parent class?